# Performance: Is expression order important in the same $project aggregation stage in MongoDB3.6?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm building my blog in node.js(v8.9.4) with MongoDB3.6. I would like to take advantage of the mongo full-text search feature in my internal search engine. For example, I can have something like the following aggregation query:

```
const page = 1;
const num = 10;
const end = { $ceil: { $divide: ['$count', num] }};
const now = { $cond: { if: { $lt: [page, end] }, then: { $literal: page }, else: end }};

const query = [
    { $match: params },
    { $sort: sort },
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 }, post: { $push: '$$ROOT' }}},
    { $project: { _id: 0,
        meta: { count: '$count', num: { $literal: num }, end, now }},
        post: { $slice: ['$post', { $multiply: [{ $add: [now, -1] }, num] }, num] },           
];
```

However, this query will throw `**Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators**'`. The way I fix it is simple, just swap the order of `meta` and `post`, i.e.

```
const query = [
    { $match: params },
    { $sort: sort },
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 }, post: { $push: '$$ROOT' }}},
    { $project: { _id: 0,
        post: { $slice: ['$post', { $multiply: [{ $add: [now, -1] }, num] }, num] },           
        meta: { count: '$count', num: { $literal: num }, end, now }},   ];
```

In my solution, it seems that Mongo query is important in expressions firing order? or is it a bug that I should report to Mongo team?

Also, I'd like to know if the more pipeline there is, the worse performance it may lead. For example, is this query better or worse (in terms of performance in a large data set):

```
const query = [
    { $match: params },
    { $sort: sort },
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 }, post: { $push: '$$ROOT' }}},
    { $project: { _id: 0,
        meta: { count: '$count', num: { $literal: num }, end, now }},
    { $project: { meta: 1,
        post: { $slice: ['$post', { $multiply: [{ $add: [$meta.now, -1] }, num] }, num] },                       
];
```

I think using `$meta.now` avoids duplicate calculations, which is good if the one is complicated, but it essentially needs an additional stage, which I'm not sure if it will slow down the performance...?!

Comment: About more pipelines is worts? Yes, it is. Aggregation works in stages, so each stage you have is an internal "for" that need to work in each document. Is the same case in double match sentence when you can use an $and operator.

Comment: I see. The reason I was asking about it is because I saw some optimization actually split a pipeline into couples in order to reduce the unnecessary volume being flushing into the next stage. So I think it is a trade-back depends on the case. But thanks for letting me know it is actually more resource demanding for operating two stages if that can be reduced to one when no significant volume changes between these two. @RaulRueda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original issue was solved after updated MongoDB, Mongoose and Mogodrive to the latest version.